# Using metadata on element to have it validated as credit card by jQuery validating plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Can I add metadata to an input's html so that the jQuery validation plugin will validate it as a credit card number?  How do I specify that all credit card types are acceptable?

(Analogous to including the class "digits" to validate that only digits are input.)

I have tried this (shot in the dark):

```
<input class="title" creditcardtypes="all" creditcard="true" name="cc-number" maxlength="16">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the creditcard rule in jquery validation plugin rather than digits

```
    rules:{
        input_name:{required:true,creditcard:true}
    },
```